# Android | StartActivityForResult wont do anything

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

i got home work to do that when i write a country in a new activity(forresult)
it will write it in the main activity and the color i write and the new activity will change the text color to what i wrote.
but the Ok and Cancel buttons wont transfer any information searched for solution with no success

MainActivity -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
TextView tvDisplayCountry;
Random crazy;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initsialize();

}

private void initsialize() {
    Button bAddCountry = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddCountry);
    bAddCountry.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvDisplayCountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayCountry);
    // ImageView ivCountryPhoto =
    // (ImageView)findViewById(r.id.ivCountryPhoto);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.bAddCountry:
        Intent countryactivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                CountryActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(countryactivityIntent, 12);

        break;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


    switch(resultCode){
    case 12:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String Country = data.getStringExtra("country");
            String Color = data.getStringExtra("color");
            tvDisplayCountry.setText(Country);
            if (Color.equalsIgnoreCase("blue")) {
                tvDisplayCountry.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLUE);
            } else if (Color.equalsIgnoreCase("yellow")) {
                tvDisplayCountry
                .setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.YELLOW);
            } else if (Color.equalsIgnoreCase("gray")) {
                tvDisplayCountry.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GRAY);
            } else if (Color.equalsIgnoreCase("red")) {
                tvDisplayCountry.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "canceld", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

CountryActivity -

```
public class CountryActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText etCountry, etColor;
String getCountry, getColor;
Button bOk,bCancel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_country);



    init();


}

private void init() {
    etColor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etColor);
    etCountry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCountry);
    bOk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bOk);
    bCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bCancel);
    bOk.setOnClickListener(this);
    bCancel.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bOk:
        Intent myIntet = new Intent();
        getCountry = etCountry.getText().toString();
        myIntet.putExtra("country",getCountry );
        getColor = etColor.getText().toString();
        myIntet.putExtra("color", getColor);

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, myIntet);
        finish();

        break;

    case R.id.bCancel:
        Intent myIntent = new Intent();

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, myIntent);
        finish();
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you get any error in LogCat?

Comment: Please add some Log.i("","Something usefull") in your code and check where there is an issue. We cannot test your whole code!

Comment: no problems in the log cat pushing ok or cancel and the main activity opens with no change

Comment: You should also consider following the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Your "Color" and "Country" variables are UpperCamelCase, which is typically reserved for classes and interfaces. Variable names should be lowerCamelCase. Android (and Java AWT) has a Color class, and your code looks like you are trying to access a static equalsIgnoreCase() method of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your `onActivityResult` -- you switch on the `resultCode` (which will be `RESULT_OK` or `RESULT_CANCELED`, not `12`).

Just change the `switch(resultCode)` to `switch(requestCode)`.